# nvidia drivers corrupt ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have the following graphics card:-

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107GL [Quadro K1200]
```

I have tried Lubuntu and Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I install new Nvidia drivers using the Additional Drivers tool. But once i install that the system corrupts. Firefox doesn't start. Rebooting requires password. All graphics applications start crashing and don't display properly. I am able to log in successfully and using terminal as well as file browser.

I have installed all possible nvidia drivers from 368 to 381 with same result so am forced to use nouveau drivers for now and cannot use Nvdia graphics card. Xubuntu 16.04 weirdly doesn't have problem with the Nvidia drivers. Does this issue need to be resolved by Nvidia or some hack at user level is suggested? This is a snapshot of the problem reported by ubuntu:-

[image]

Comment: Most likely you didn't install the drivers correctly and the only version recommended is **375**: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114708/en-us (Do NOT download, FYI only).

Comment: I installed 375 using Additional Drivers. And when i rebooted that's when the problems started.